# Adding a string with spaces to a stack

Tags: python

I'm working on developing a mini-language in Python (not really, just a few commands for a personal project).

Here's the code:

```
class FlashCard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.commands = {'addQuestion':self.addQuestion}
        self.stack = []
        self.questions = {}


    def addQuestion(self):
        question = self.stack.pop()
        answer = input(question)


    def interpret(self,expression):
        for token in expression.split():
            if token in self.commands:
                operator = self.commands[token]
                operator()
            else:
                self.stack.append(token)

i = FlashCard()
i.interpret('testing this addQuestion')
```

The interpret function will only pull the last word (this) from the string. Is there a way to make it pull the entire line?

Thank you!

Comment: From the answers that are coming in, im confused at what you really want the result to be. Are you trying to retain the entire expression that was passed to interpret or only the tokens that arent command tokens? Also, if a command token is found in the middle of the expression then it will get called and act only on the tokens that have been captured before it. Is that also what you want?

Comment: @jdi - Only the OP knows for sure, but from the code I would expect he is building a parser for custom commands such as `What is the Turkish translation of "cat"? addQuestion` [That should probably add a new flash card with the question "What is the Turkish translation of "cat"?". I may be wrong though! :)

Comment: You are correct, mac. Each question should stand by itself, and new interpret lines should not be joined with old ones.

Comment: @mac - right. if he were specifically making it parse expressions where the command is always at the end. But I guess I assumed he was trying to interpret an entire line. Otherwise he could have just split and checked the last argument in the list instead of scanning each element. This example code looks just like a test but would ultimately parse for more standard word tokens.

Comment: @zackt147 - ok then if the command token is always going to be at the end, then I think its more efficient to not loop over each token and check it against your command dict. Just split the expression, pop the last item off and do self.stack.extend(left_over_tokens). Save yourself the overhead of doing an unnecc loop and key check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since stack is a list, and you are calling the `pop` method without arguments, what you will get is the last elements in the list. You probably want to transform the list in a space-separated string, instead:

```
def addQuestion(self):
    question = ' '.join(self.stack)
    answer = input(question)
```

Observe that the side effect of `pop` and `join` are different. `pop` will modify the original list:

```
>>> stack = ['testing', 'this']
>>> stack.pop()
'this'
>>> stack
['testing']
```

while `join` won't:

```
>>> stack = ['testing', 'this']
>>> ' '.join(stack)
'testing this'
>>> stack
['testing', 'this']
```

---

**Edit (see comments of OP below):** To parse multiple lines / commands in the same input, you could do different things. The easiest that comes to my mind: flush the stack after the call to `operator()`:

```
if token in self.commands:
    operator = self.commands[token]
    operator()
    self.stack = []
```

---

**Edit 2 (see my own comment below):** Here's the complete example using a list of strings:

```
class FlashCard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.commands = {'addQuestion':self.addQuestion}

    def addQuestion(self, phrase):
        answer = raw_input(phrase)

    def interpret(self, expressions):
        for expression in expressions.split('\n'):
            phrase, command = expression.rsplit(' ', 1)
            if command in self.commands:
                operator = self.commands[command]
                operator(phrase)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Invalid command')

expressions = '''testing this addQuestion
testing that addQuestion
testing error removeQuestion'''
i = FlashCard()
i.interpret(expressions)
```

HTH!

Comment: problem is that it still wont be the complete line since its not going to append the matching command token. its only appending words that dont match the commands. seems like he would want to append all the tokens...capture the command token..and call it at the end

Comment: @jdi - If I understand what the OP wants to do, that should be the correct behaviour, but I might be wrong though! :)

Comment: @mac - totally agree with you that it grabs all the tokens on the stack. I think im really just trying to figure out what the op intends the output to be

Comment: Ah, I think I might have run into the problem with join.  There are going to be multiple interpret statements. That works for 1 line, ie `i.interpret("Who are you? addQuestion")` but if I were to do another interpret line after that, it would join both in the next question prompt. I was using pop to remove the previous item from the stack, so the next statement would stand by itself. Is there still a way to do this?

Comment: @zackt147 - See edit. You should consider if a stack is really the best design choice though: if your "commands" are one each line, then you could probably first split them in a list with `commands.split('\n')` and then process each element of this list passing it as an argument to the `operator()`. In turn, `operator should assume that the last world is the command... Aaah... better post some code. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your addQuestion to use the entire stack.

```python
def addQuestion(self):
    question = ' '.join(self.stack) + '?'
    self.stack = []
    answer = raw_input(question)
```

I was getting errors with `input` so I changed that to `raw_input`.  I think that's what you want.